# Issues trying with matricies with OpenTK using GL4

Tags: opentk

I've been trying for the past week to figure this out but I can't wrap my head around it,

```
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec2 texCoord;
uniform mat4 ortho;

//as i write this i just finished the fragment shader and fml
void main()
{
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = ortho * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}
```

this is my current OpenTK/OpenGL Vertex shader, and no matter what I do, whenever 'ortho' is present nothing renders.

```
        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);


            Palette.Use();
            texture1.Use(TextureUnit.Texture1);

            //shaders.SetMatrix4("view", mat_view);


            mat_ortho = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0.0f, Width, Height, 0.0f, -1f, 1.0f);
            shaders.SetMatrix4("ortho", mat_ortho);

            shaders.Use();



            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indexes.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetError());
            Context.SwapBuffers();
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        }
```

I've tried moving vvv everywhere in the function and nothing helps

```
            mat_ortho = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0.0f, Width, Height, 0.0f, -1f, 1.0f);
            shaders.SetMatrix4("ortho", mat_ortho);

            shaders.Use();
```

I have no idea What I'm doing wrong, if anyone can assist me it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the vertex coordinates (`aPosition`)? Are they in between the near and far plane of the orthographic projection?

Comment: How do you load the texture? What does the fragment shader do?

Comment: Have you tried using the shader before setting it's uniforms? That is the only problem I can see from the code snippets. Though the problem might lie somewhere else (are you checking for glErrors or shader compiler errors?)